# Store app get access to webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-store-apps

I got a working connection to a webservice, now I got a different webservice (https instead of http) and the code does not work anymore. Does anyone know what i have to change in order for it to work with https?

```
public AppWebService_PortClient openConn()
{
    BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding { };
    binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
    binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows;

    EndpointAddress epa = new EndpointAddress("https://172.16.restOfURL");
    AppWebService_PortClient ws = new AppWebService_PortClient(binding, epa);
    ws.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("theUser", "ThePassword", "TheDomain");

    return ws;
}
```

This provide me the following error:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll
>
> Additional information: The type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink.Behavior,

If i just press continue it will eventually go further and tells me

> A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll
>
> Additional information: The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'.

This is the code to talk to the webservice,

```
public async Task getData()
{
    if (IsRunning)
        return;
    try
    {
        IsRunning = true;
        Groups = new ObservableCollection<ProductGroup>();
        var ws = referance.openConn();
        Item itemSimple = new Item();

        GetItems wsrequest = new GetItems(itemSimple, "", "", "0");
        GetItems_Result result = await ws.GetItemsAsync(wsrequest);

        ItemCategory ic = new ItemCategory();
        GetItemCategory catrequest = new GetItemCategory(ic);
        GetItemCategory_Result catresult = await ws.GetItemCategoryAsync(catrequest);

        var results = catresult.itemCategoryExport.ItemCategorys;
        foreach (ItemCategorys itemc in results)
        {
            ProductGroup p = new ProductGroup(itemc.Code, itemc.Description, "/Assets/logo.jpg");
            Groups.Add(p);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        IsRunning = false;
    }
```

Comment: Where is `AppWebService_PortClient` defined? Was this a class generated by Visual Studio's "Web Reference" proxy generator?